# Are these 33 year old cables inside a CRT TV dangerous/dying?

Tags: safety, consumer-electronics, history

Today I finally opened up and dedusted my 33 year old TV, fearing both a fire hazard with decades of dust bunnies piled up in there (or so I imagined) and all sorts of possible non-lethal issues arising from the dust being in there.

Sadly, I discovered that some/a lot of the dust seemed to have... morphed into some kind of sticky goo which would not come off at all from the compressed air (from cans). This was both surprising and frustrating.

I took a close-up photo of what I consider to be the worst part. Again: this is **after** I had removed all the dust that could be removed. What's left is hard for me to describe, but it doesn't look good to me.

I'm primarily wondering if this is dangerous or what I should expect in terms of this TV surviving. I was hoping to use it for the rest of my life, and naively thought that all I had to do was to open it up and remove the dust every few decades.

Why does it seems like it has melted goo on all the cables and whatnot?

Also, to make it clear: the TV is working and has a great picture. And that's in spite of rather rough handling today after I was convinced that it had died on me after the compressed air... but it only had to rest for a few hours and then suddenly came on again.

I am unable to do any kind of repairs of this TV, and there is no longer anyone here who can fix it, so I feel like I'm using/abusing an ancient antique from a bygone era. Modern TVs just don't produce the same magic image. I hope you can tell me good news about the photo, in spite of my strong worries...

[image]

Comment: Could die tomorrow, could die 2 years from now, may last 10 more years... No way to tell.

Comment: the "melted goo" may be cigarette smoke or kitchen grease